# Module structure Angular, right using shared component in module?

Tags: angular

I have try to make a right decision about design project Angular.

Application has main entity as **Order**.

Order has **three** cases of usage:

1. Distribution
2. Assigning
3. Execution

I have decide to create the three modules: `DistributionModule, AssigningModule, ExecutionModule` with entity point as `DistributionComponent, AssigningComponent, ExecutionComponent`.

Each entity point component contains two components:

1. SideBarComponent
2. ContentComponent

Each Order has **details**:

1. Order short
2. Order address
3. Order appliciant
4. Order history

All of then is used inside `OrderDetailsComponent`.

**Schema is for list of order with own sidebar:**

```
OrderDistributionModule
   OrderDistributionComponent <-- Entry component point with route outlet
     OrderDistributionWrapperComponent
         OrderSideBarComponent
         OrderListComponent
```

**Schema is for details of order with own sidebar:**

```
OrderDistributionModule
   OrderDistributionComponent <-- Entry component point with route outlet
     OrderDistributionWrapperDetailsComponent
         OrderSideBarComponent
         OrderDetailsComponent
             OrderDetailsAddressComponent
             OrderDetailsApplicianComponent
```

I am doubt in wrappers:

```
1. OrderDistributionWrapperComponent
2. OrderDistributionWrapperDetailsComponent
```

I want to use routing like:

```
{
        path: 'distribution',
        loadChildren: () =>
            import('./modules/orders-distribution-module/orders-distribution.module').then((m) => m.OrdersDistributionModule),
    },
```

Then `OrdersDistributionModule` has children routes:

```
   {
        path: '',
        component: OrderDistributionComponent,
        children: [
          {
             path: 'orders',
              component: OrderDistributionWrapperComponent,
              children: [
                  path: 'details/:id',
                  component: OrderDistributionWrapperDetailsComponent
               ]
           }
        ]
    },
```

What do you think?

My problem is I try to use:

```
 children: [
   path: 'details/:id',
   component: OrderDistributionWrapperDetailsComponent
]
```

> It means parent component `OrderDistributionWrapperComponent` should
>   have route outlet, but it does not. Route outlet is only in
>   `OrderDistributionComponent`.

Actually I can move `path: 'details/:id',` upper in the same level with `path: 'orders'`:

```
{
   path: 'orders',
   component: OrderDistributionWrapperComponent
},

{ 
   path: 'orders/details/:id',
   component: OrderDistributionWrapperDetailsComponent

}
```

But I dont like that `orders/details/:id` like as separate component, not inside main entity `orders`. And I dont line duplication name in route `' ----->orders/details/:id'`

Comment: Sorry for these hard questions, Can you provide some sample images of the UI you are trying to achieve with this design?

Comment: I have a feeling that the design can be simplified and your UI can look and perform better for your use cases. Could you please provide a sample UI image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `OrderDetailsComponent` is used in all the modules, it is advised to create a shared module and import that shared module in all of the modules.

Shared Module should declare and export `OrderDetailsComponent`.

**Note:** 
Angular Modules are introduced to give performance benefits on run time. Modules are lazy-loaded, so the time to load the page for the first time is drastically reduced. After the first load, only the components/modules which are needed will be loaded on runtime. A key point to note here is that Modules also add a slight delay because of the time it takes to load on runtime. Unless you have many components in each of those modules, it doesn't make sense to create separate modules.

I would suggest you create `Distribution`, `Assigning`, and `Execution` modules only when you have many components in each of those modules.

Comment: Do you mean create `OrderDetailsModule` that has entry point `OrderDetailsComponent` and dependencies?

`Order short Component 

Order address Component

Order appliciant Component

Order history Component`

What if `OrderDetailsComponent` has own SideBarComponent?

Comment: @MeganClerc Correct me if I am wrong, Your application basically has 3 pages, One for Distribution, One for Execution and One for Assigning. Each of these pages show a list of orders and some details about those orders. On the sidebar, you have links to each of those pages (Distribution, Execution and Assiging pages). On clicking on each each navigation, the respective page will be loaded.
Is that it?

Comment: eh your description of modules isn't quite accurate. They're actually introduced as a code organization tool. Lazy Loading is an optional feature that makes use of modules.

Comment: Yeah. That too. But major advantage of using modules is for lazy loading and for separation of concerns. It helps in loading only the set of components which are needed for the user and reduces the overhead of loading all the components from the whole application.

Comment: @bryan60 The thing is, code organization can also be achieved with folders. But modules functionality is provided for performance reasons.

Comment: @peter Each page has list of orders and on the left sidebar with hash links. When I open details order I see another sidebar and details content with nested details components.

Comment: @MeganClerc If it is not an issue, can you update the question with an image for the page you are trying to build? It will help me in assisting you better.

Comment: Modules themselves have no performance impact whatsoever on an application. Lazy Loading, a feature of the router, does. Modules existed long before lazy loading. They are a code organization tool.

Comment: Okay I will edit now my question

Comment: @peter Done, check please question again

Comment: @bryan60 yeah. Makes sense. The main idea of Modules might be for code organisation, but why would anyone want to use modules currently and go through the trouble of declarations, imports and exports? There should be an advantage apart from just code organisation that modules must be solving these days right?

Comment: Could you help me with structure?